# Take a screenshot of an application that is not ours

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-dependencies, screenshot

I want to create an application in flutter that can take screenshot of the home screen or of other applications of the phone on IOS and android. It would be possible thanks to a bubble overlay that displays on the phone at anytime. When you press it, it takes a screenshot so the content that you were looking at is in the picture.

Is it possible? If it is, can you help me ?

I checked for the screenshot package but i don't think it can take screenshot of another application.
I didn't see any other package but nothing indicates that it is not possible

Thank you

Comment: Pretty likely not possible.